# Make image respect the font-size property?

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following problem:

I have some text here, it has the `font-size` property set to 24pt. It looks like this:

```html
<span style="font-size:24pt">lorem ipsum: <a href="/mywebpage/" target="_blank" id="l">even the size of the links change! cool.</a></span>
```

Everything is fine with that.

Though, I'd like it if somehow, we could make the images inside that `span` tag respect the `font-size` property.

(Basically, I want to make the images look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olIHq.png))

Sadly, they look like this, which is not what I want..:

```html
<span style="font-size:24pt">lorem ipsum: <a href="/mywebpage/" target="_blank" id="l">link</a><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ucJK.png"></span>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately images will not respect the font size property.  It would be easier to just manually set the image width, or set the container height and use flexbox or height 100%, it really depends on the context

Comment: Set `height: 1em` on the image. Leave the width alone so it maintains aspect ratio.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks alot!! It works! Please publish this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `height: 1em;`, or if that's too much `height: 0.95em;` or whatever value in combination with `width: auto`  to adjust the image height in relation to the currently used line-height / font-size.

Just change the font-size in my snippet and you'll see the effect. I used 0.75em to adjust it.

```css
.x {
  font-size: 32px;
}

img {
  height: 0.75em;
  width: auto;

}
```

```html
<span class="x">lorem ipsum: <a href="/mywebpage/" target="_blank" id="l">link</a><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ucJK.png"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `height` and `width` attributes for the `<img>` in HTML, you can have it all the way from `1px` each, from what I see that image looks a lot larger than just one square pixel, use the `margin` in CSS to adjust its position if necessary!

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `<img>` and text don't behave the same!

Comment: I think I didnt made myself clear.. Sorry. Lets say you can ONLY change the styling of the span tag, how could one solve that problem?

Comment: I still don't understand, the contents within the span tag are what you assign them to be, however, images aren't the same. Sure, it will help the images stay in place within that element but the size of the image is decided with pixels. When using margins you can use negative values as well!

Answer (score 0):

Use the image as background like below:

```css
span {
 padding-right:1.3em;
 background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ucJK.png) right/auto 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size:24pt">lorem ipsum: <a href="/mywebpage/" target="_blank" id="l">link</a></span>
<br>
<span style="font-size:20pt">lorem ipsum: <a href="/mywebpage/" target="_blank" id="l">link</a></span>
<br>
<span style="font-size:14pt">lorem ipsum: <a href="/mywebpage/" target="_blank" id="l">link</a></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, but inside my project Bob Ross can be anywere inside the span tag.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var textSize = $("#text").css("font-size");
console.log(textSize);
$("#img").css("height", textSize)
```

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="font-size:24px" id="text">lorem ipsum: <a href="/mywebpage/" target="_blank" id="l">link</a><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ucJK.png" id="img"></span>
```

This can be achieved by jQuery like this, Don't know the exact requirements but this could be a trick, first get the size of text and then give the same height to img